# Using GPS with JSON data

Tags: java, android, json, gps, parse-platform

I have an activity that displays a list of activities (name, picture, brief description), and where those information are derived from JSON data. I am trying to figure out how I could add a criteria where only the list of activities that falls within lets say 100km would be shown.

I was thinking of adding the following to my JSON data
"location_code":"(49, -123)",  where 49 represents latitude  and -123 longitude, and what would happen is that it would evaluate the location_code of the activity in respect to the current location of the user and would only populate activities that falls within that range.

Below is my current code:

```
public class CultureEventsActivity extends Activity{

    private static final String URL_WEB_SERVICE = "http://dooba.elasticbeanstalk.com/analytics/culture.php";
    private GridView gv;
    private ArrayList<Events_List> container;
    private ArrayList<Events_List> items;
    public Uri list_item_bac;
    public String list_item_name;
    public String list_item_description;
    public String list_item_location;
    public String single_list_item_description;
    public String list_item_price;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.events_list_layout);
        gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        container = new ArrayList<Events_List>();
        //download JSON
        listDownload();



        GridView s = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        s.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(CultureEventsActivity.this,CultureEventsSingleItemActivity.class);

                intent.putExtra("list_item_name", container.get(position).getList_item_title());
                intent.putExtra("list_item_price", container.get(position).getList_item_price());
                intent.putExtra("list_item_location", container.get(position).getList_item_location());
                intent.putExtra("single_list_item_description", container.get(position).getSingle_list_item_description());
                intent.putExtra("list_item_bac", container.get(position).getList_item_bac().toString());
                intent.putExtra("list_item_purchase_code", container.get(position).getList_item_purchase_code());
                startActivity(intent); //start Activity
            }
        });
    }
    public void listDownload(){
        RequestQueue volley = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        JsonObjectRequest json = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET, URL_WEB_SERVICE, null, ResponseListener(), ErrorListener());
        volley.add(json);
    }

    private Response.Listener<JSONObject> ResponseListener() {
        return new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    //your JSON Array
                    JSONArray array = response.getJSONArray("list_item");
                    for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){
                        container.add(convertirAnuncio(array.getJSONObject(i)));
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                gv.setAdapter(new AdapterEvents(getApplicationContext(),container));
                }
            };
        };


    private Response.ErrorListener ErrorListener() {
        return new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) { }
        };
    }

    //object JSON
    private final Events_List convertirAnuncio(JSONObject obj) throws JSONException {
        long id = obj.getLong("id"); //id 
        String list_item_name = obj.getString("list_item_name"); 
        String list_item_location = obj.getString("list_item_location"); 
        String list_item_description = obj.getString("list_item_description");
        String list_item_price = obj.getString("list_item_price");
        String list_item_purchase_code = obj.getString("list_item_purchase_code");
        String single_list_item_description = obj.getString("single_list_item_description");
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(obj.getString("list_item_bac"));
        return new Events_List(id, list_item_location, single_list_item_description,list_item_name,list_item_description,list_item_price,list_item_purchase_code, uri, uri);
    }
}
```

As of now the code populates all activities, and does not filter by search zone.  It would also be nice if I could include a constant like private String SEARCH_DISTANCE = 100KM;

PS. I am also using Parse, where the current user is derived from Parse, but I am not sure if that's relevant.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have been trying to figure this out since a while.
If you require any further clarification, let me know.